# Does Russia stamp passports of foreign tourists while entering or exiting Russia?

Tags: russia, passport-stamps

I'd like to go to Russia but I'm worried that Russian stamps might look bad on my passport.

Comment: Unless you're planning to visit Ukraine, it won't be a problem.

Comment: Unless you visit some illegally occupied Ukrainian territory, why do you expect that visiting Ukraine would be a problem?

Comment: @DimitriVulis As a comparison, Israel does not stamp passports because several other countries would not admit you if you had simply visited Israel.  I think the OP is fearing something similar.

Comment: Even if you visited some of Ukrainian territory controlled by Russia, this is where no passports are stamped additionally, so Ukraine has no legal means of knowing that you crossed there (but there are espionage/data leaks of course)

Comment: @PeterM there are countries that explicitly state that that's their policy. AFAIK there's no country with such a policy against people visiting the Russian Federation. Not even the areas it occupies.

Comment: @JonathanReez  I would visit Ukraine when their airports start working. I'd probably visit both countries multiple times in the future. That would be a problem?

Comment: @littleadv In a comment under Alex's answer, the OP states that there is a policy of not being able to enter Ukraine after having a Russian stamp.  I have no real knowledge of this situation, but it seems counter to your understanding.

Comment: I googled a bit/. According to several news stories, Ukraine considers visiting occupied territories as a violation of [Article 332 of their Criminal Code](https://sherloc.unodc.org/cld/uploads/res/document/ukr/2001/criminal-code-of-the-republic-of-ukraine-en_html/Ukraine_Criminal_Code_as_of_2010_EN.pdf).  Don't post about it in social media if you do go there. However I found no evidence that Ukrainians care whether someone visited Russia proper. This claim sounds like Russian disinformation to me.

Comment: @PeterM I'm not familiar with such an issue, and I know people visiting both countries.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that the passport might also have exit stamps when leaving the country of origin, even if there are no entry stamps. So the customs officer may legitimately ask where one went.

Answer (score 11):

My personal experience:

I have a U.S. passport.

I got a 3-year Russian visa.

The border guards stamped my passport every time I flew in or out, which was quite a few times.

I don't know whether they stamp every time the passports from other countries, that don't need visas.

Answer (score 8):

Getting a stamp is not Russia-specific, every country I have visited which required me to have a passport also stamped it on entry.

Unless you enter Russia through the occupied territories (which Ukraine considers illegal border crossing), there should be no negative impact from having that stamp, at least for now.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Russian border control stamps you passport on entering and exiting.
It is an old Soviet custom. Now all information about your movements through the border is kept in computer systems, but... tradition is tradition.
We, Russians, have many traditions about foreigners. )))

Comment: What do you think would happen if a tourist asked not to stamp their passport?

Comment: I am afraid it is out of the question. 
You enter with a stamp or do not enter at all.

Comment: Thanks @AlexSidorov If I have Ukraine stamps on my passport, can I enter Russia? In both cases, as a tourist

Comment: I think you can. The fact that you visited Ukraine must not be a problem.
There  should be some additional considerations to prevent you from entering Russia.

Comment: I know those who have Russian stamps can't enter Ukraine. So maybe Russia is following the same policy? Reciprocity

Comment: "those who have Russian stamps can't enter Ukraine" I doubt that this is true. Can you cite sources?

Comment: Bald and bankrupt tried to enter Ukraine after visiting Russia but couldn't

Comment: I know someone who has a bunch of Russian stamps and had no trouble visiting Ukraine this year. I have no idea who you're talking about. Were they given a reason for not being allow into Ukraine?

Comment: What is his nationality?

Comment: AmCit. Meanwhile I found the B&B video you mentioned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ljw2X6qpoOs

Comment: Do you think other "advanced" countries don't stamp your passport at border control?

Comment: *It is an old Soviet custom* It is also an old Yankee custom. And Frenchie. And many others. Now that I think of it, I probably got a stamp everywhere where I presented my passport.

Comment: "It is an old Soviet custom" - I have literally never heard of a country except Israel that doesn't stamp passports, and I've travelled most of Europe and not an insignificant chunk of the world.

Comment: @Davor Cuba used to not stamp passports until the Obama-era thaw in relations with the US. It reverted to not stamping in Jan 2021 after the US put Cuba back on its State Sponsors of Terrorism list. IIRC instead Immigration just logs the entry/exit in their system and gives you a bit of paper as proof which you are supposed to hand back when you leave.

Comment: Schengen countries generally don't stamp passports of Schengen citizens (and I guess many other countries don't stamp their own citizens' passports either).

Comment: I'm German, and I just visited the UK with the family. A passport was required, but we got no stamps. It is definitely not the case that *every* country stamps *every* passport.

Comment: @StephanKolassa It is very much the default though. EU countries have agreed not to stamp other EU passports, what you saw in the UK is just a leftover of that. And even that is only true for visitors and UK residents, you'd have had your passport stamped, were you arriving for work.

Answer (score 2):

Russia stamps on entry and exit just like most other countries. It doesn't matter what country your passport is from - you will get the two stamps (and a shot of vodka - j/k).
I cannot imagine a scenario where a Russian stamp in your passport would cause you a problem in the future.

Comment: Are you differentiating between having a stamp and having visited? Because having visited, say, Iraq can indeed cause complications for *some* people visiting *some* third countries. Stamp or no stamp.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Russia is not Iraq, and the answer specifically says Russia.

Comment: @Davor Russia could be added to that list at any time.